# How to construct query with AND restrictions on one column in binding table of M:N relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have binding table between author and publisher. Each author can be connected to many publishers and one publisher can be connected to many authors. It is M:N relationship. Therefore I have binding table. Of course, there can be also author which is connected just to one of the publishers.

I want to select all the authors which are connected to Publisher1 and at the same time to Publisher2. I do not want to have in result set authors which are just connected to Publisher1 or just to Publisher2. Simply Publisher1 AND Publisher2.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT author_id FROM author_publisher where publisher_id = 1 AND where publisher_id = 2
```

But it did not work. I got empty set.

I was trying to use the intersect:

```
SELECT author_id FROM author_publisher where publisher_id = 1 
Intersect 
Select author_id FROM author_publisher where publisher_id = 2
```

But I am using MySQL and it seems that this is not supported.

Does anyone have any advice how to construct such a query?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a non-correlated sub-query... Not the most performant way, but you could try:

```
SELECT author_id FROM author_publisher WHERE publisher_id = 1
and author_id in (SELECT author_id FROM author_publisher WHERE publisher_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two joins against the binding table:

```sql
SELECT author.* FROM author
  JOIN author_publisher AS ap1
    ON ap1.author_id = author.author_id AND ap1.publisher_id = 1
  JOIN author_publisher AS ap2
    ON ap2.author_id = author.author_id AND ap2.publisher_id = 2
```

or, equivalently, with the `JOIN ... USING ()` syntax, and moving the `publisher_id` conditions to the `WHERE` senction:

```sql
SELECT author.* FROM author
  JOIN author_publisher AS ap1 USING (author_id)
  JOIN author_publisher AS ap2 USING (author_id)
 WHERE ap1.publisher_id = 1 AND ap2.publisher_id = 2
```

If you only want the ID, you can even simplify this to a single join of the binding table against itself:

```sql
SELECT author_id
  FROM author_publisher AS ap1
  JOIN author_publisher AS ap2 USING (author_id)
 WHERE ap1.publisher_id = 1 AND ap2.publisher_id = 2
```